# Придаточная часть сложноподчинённого предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Придаточные изъяснительные, насколько я знаю, подчеркиваются целиком как дополнение. Но на одном сайте в предложении "потом я понял, как нужно поступать" слова придаточной части были подчеркнуты как обстоятельство и сказуемое соответственно. Почему так, а не целиком как дополнение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При синтаксическом разборе сложного предложения составляется его **грамматическая схема**, а подчеркивается только **предикативная основа** (подлежащее и сказуемое).

Поэтому подчеркивание как дополнение  **может быть видом частного разбора**: так мы показываем, что изъяснительное придаточное занимает место дополнения в общей структуре сложного предложения и отвечает на вопрос ЧТО, характерный для дополнения.

**Как единое целое** подчеркиваются, к примеру, обособленные члены.

Также можно поставить **другую частную задачу** ― разобрать каждое предложение в составе сложного как простое, тогда надо будет подчеркивать отдельно все члены предложения.